# problem with tf No transform from /laser_link to frame /odom

Tags: rviz, ros-groovy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

I am new to ros, i am trying to view pointcloud in rviz. But i have problem with tf.

I am publishing `/odom -> /base_link` using [tf::TransformBroadcaster]

and  `/base_link -> /laser_link` as static transform from launch file.

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_link_tfS" args="1 3 2 0 0 0 base_link laser_link  1000" />
```

But in rviz its showing `No transform from [/laser_link] to frame [/odom]`

I tried urdf file but i didnt solve the problem.

thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

output pdf is here http:// www. tempsend.com/AEAD417228 (remove spaces)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/116446/problem-with-tf-no-transform-from-/laser_link-to-frame-/odom/) by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3034 on 2014-01-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on 2014-01-10**:
could you show frames graph ? you can generate pdf file of it with `rosrun tf view_frames`. Also you could try increasing publishing rate from 1000 to 100

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-10**:
@rock-ass frames pdf added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most likely cause I can see from your description of the problem is that the timestamp of the tf transform you´re broadcasting is not correct. As requested also in a comment, you should edit your post with further info. You can also try both of these commands:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo base_link laser_link 
rosrun tf tf_echo odom base_link
```

If the first one fails to show a transfom, your static publisher does not work. if the second one fails, your TransformBroadcaster is the culprit.

/edit: As you can see from the posted frames.pdf, the transform between odom and base_link published to tf is 44 years old, while the transform published to by the static publishers is timestamped ~0.5 seconds into the future (as it should be).
This suggests you don´t timestamp the data when publishing via the TransformBroadcaster correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-10**:
for both commands its showing warning  TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame /imu_link at time 0 according to authority /odom_publisher_node

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-01-10**:
See edit above. Fix the timestamp and try if it works then.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-10**:
It worked after adding ros::Time::now();
thanks

**Comment by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on 2014-01-10**:
Insightful answer, didn't thought of timestamps in first place